# What happened to Puppeteer's BrowserFetcher?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, chromium

At the moment, all documentation for `createBrowserFetcher` and `BrowserFetcher` stands removed. I haven't been following the development of puppeteer, so don't know what happened. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I needed to download chromium manually, and came upon some answers mentioning `createBrowserFetcher`. But when I looked up the docs, I didn't find it. I know it existed as some point because I can see [questions](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/9139) about it, but the [page](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.browserfetcher) for it doesn't exist in the website.

As it stands currently, it has been removed from Puppeteer. All I want to know why it was removed, when, and are there any alternatives. If anyone can point me to relevant issues, PRs, questions, answers, it will help a lot.

Comment: so annoying that they didn't even mention it as a breaking change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the first step was [using `new BrowserFetcher` directly instead of the `createBrowserFetcher` wrapper](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/pull/9079). This was released in [19.0.0](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/releases/tag/v19.0.0).

Later, it looks like the maintainers decided to break browser fetching out to a separate package: [@puppeteer/browsers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@puppeteer/browsers), initially released [2023/2/22](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/releases/tag/browsers-v0.0.1).

From [PR #9647](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/pull/9647):

> This PR introduces a new package that is the refactored version of the BrowserFetcher.
>
> The new package will encapsulate all the Node-specific code related to the launching/downloading of the browsers (the code that is currently in the node folder of puppeteer-core). It will also simplify and unify the workflow to support more browsers. This PR implements two functions `fetch` and `canFetch`.

Subsequent PRs fleshed out the new package, and [#10107](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/pull/10107) removed the `BrowserFetcher` namespace from Puppeteer. Additional PRs like [#10129](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/pull/10129) removed `BrowserFetcher` from the docs and pointed the links to the new package.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the new page for the Browser API is https://pptr.dev/browsers-api